# WordPress - Forcing SSL with .htaccess leads to redirect loop when using Polylang

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https, polylang

I have this issue with WordPress site that uses Polylang Plugin. I have redirected all traffic to https version with .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

After I changed the "default language" setting in Polylang, I started getting "Too many redirects" error. If I remove the above lines from .htaccess, the error goes away.

Is there a way to force all traffic to https version while using Polylang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve this by forcing ssl in functions.php instead.

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multilanguage plugins have redirects of their own, which in this case probably causes the loop. If you re-save the settings of the polylang plugin, it should be fixed.

Removing the .htaccess redirects of Really Simple SSL is not necessary.

Comment: I tried re-saving the settings, no effect. Not using Really Simple SSL plugin.

Comment: Remove the .htaccess redirects. also re-saving the permalink settings

Comment: If I remove them, I get rid of the error yes, but I want to force https.

Comment: thanks, it worked for me: just hit save button in polylang settings -> url